# Installing my certificate in genymotion android emulator

Tags: android, ssl, genymotion

I have my own self-signed certificate that I wish to install it in my android genymotion emulator. I go to settings->Security->Install from SD Card, response, No certificates found in the SD card. I have a shared folder created and have mounted that into the emulator. I can see the cert file in that location too, /mnt/shared/sdcard/cert/xxx.cert, where sdcard is the shared directory I created. I emulate Galaxy Nexus - 4.2.2 API. Where should I place the cert file so that the android system find a new file? Is there a path where I can store the cert file directly? Any other way to install my cert?

Answer (score 4):

1. Put your certificate in: `/sdcard/`  folder
2. Go to the Settings ->
   Security -> Install from SD card
3. Follow instructions and install your certificate file
4. Reboot the device

Comment: Someone for some reason downvoted. Please, let me know what is not clear for you? I'll try to help.

Comment: 2019 update on points 1 & 2 : 
1) You can drag and drop your certificate in the simulator window to get it in `/sdcard/` folder
2) Go to the `Settings` -> `Security & Location` -> `Encryption & Credentials` -> `Install from SD card` -> Open burger menu and select `Downloads` folder -> select your certificate

Answer (score 2):

In Android, the certificate you want to install has to be placed at the root of the sdcard folder.

The good path to put your file on the last version of Genymotion is:

```
/mnt/sdcard/
```

or

```
/sdcard/
```

on the Genymotion File Manager the folder is

```
/storage/emulated/0
```

Comment: hi, we have a script that places our certs in `/system/etc/security/cacerts/` would we be better off using the location you have specified ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Retrieve the Subject Hash for your target certificate. Assuming your target certificate is named `ca.crt` you can get your Subject Hash by running the following: `openssl x509 -inform PEM -subject_hash -in ca.crt`
2. Create a copy of your target cert named with the HASH output from above appended with `.0`. Like so, `HASH.0`.
3. Finally, use `adb` to copy your new cert to `/system/etc/security/cacerts/` on your target emulator

Complete detailed step-by-step instructions can be found here: https://kodmunki.wordpress.com/2018/02/07/install-a-self-signed-ssl-android-emulator-genymotion/